# C GTK+ idle function run once

Tags: c, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to write a GUI and switch on and off a LED on a Raspberry Pi 3B+.

I added an idle function to `gtk` main loop and ran only once, the counter (`szamlalo`) did not increase. When i write:

```
printf("\r"); //?
```

behind `szamlalo++` all works well.

Have someone any idea?

my full code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include "EasyPIO.h"

GtkWidget *label;
unsigned int b=0;
unsigned int szamlalo = 0;



void idle()
{
    if(szamlalo > 100)
    {
        digitalWrite(2,!digitalRead(2));
        szamlalo = 0;
        printf("led\n\r");
    }
    else
    {
        szamlalo++;
        printf("\r"); //?
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkBuilder  *builder;
    GtkWidget   *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "ui.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    pioInit();
    pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
    g_idle_add((void*)&idle,NULL);

    label = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "cimke"));

    g_object_unref(builder);
    gtk_widget_show(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}

void bezaras()
{
    printf("kilépés\r\n");
    gtk_main_quit();
}

void btn_clicked()
{
    if(b==0)
    {
        gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(label), "ügyes vagy!");
        b=1;
    }
    else
    {
        b=0;
        gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(label), "de tényleg!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the only change you did was to add the `printf("\r");` ? And if you remove that line it stops to work again ?

Comment: yes x2, i checked this

Comment: @bruno this makes perfectly sense as it just changes the unspecified return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You invoke undefined behaviour:

```
void idle()
{
...
}
```

According to the [manual for g_idle_add](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add) the signature of the function has to be `gboolean (*GSourceFunc) (gpointer user_data);` and the function has to return a boolean value.

> If the function returns FALSE it is automatically removed from the list of event sources and will not be called again.

Not returning a value while the caller expects one and uses the return value is undefined behaviour.

If you simply return from the function you might have some 0 bytes in the location that is used for return values which is treated as `FALSE`. After calling `printf` you probably have the return value from `printf` in that location and as you print 1 character, that value is 1 which is not `FALSE` and the function is called again.

You also have a wrong cast:

```
g_idle_add((void*)&idle,NULL);
```

The type `void*` is compatible to all data pointers. You abuse it to force a wrong function type into the call.
Use a proper function instead and remove the cast. If you require a cast for a function type, most likely something is wrong in the way you use the function.

Answer (score 0):

Make you country `volatile` as it was probable optimized out by the compiler

Comment: As this variable is only used in `idle()` function once per function call, I don't think this can be the reason.

Comment: The function is not called from anywhere visible for the compiler in the normal execution path so this variable has to be volatile. Because it is not, Ops program behaves this way

Comment: Unless the whole `idle` function is removed by the linker, this variable cannot be removed. IMHO `volatile` would only help if the variable was read in a loop in another function than `idle`. The compiler cannot optimize accesses to variables between function calls.

Comment: If your assumption was right, why would an extra call to `printf` make any difference?